# The app failed to resume properly from snapped view

Tags: windows-8

When my Windows 8 app returns from snapped view, it sends the user to the first page of the app. I received a failure notice that my app fails to resume properly, however, Windows passed it before. Is it illegal to send the user to the first page, when the user resumes from snapped mode? How do I tell the app what page the user is located and to restore it?

When my app enter exits snapped mode, this code runs:

```
void ShowCurrentViewState()
    {
        //this.UpdateUnsnapButtonState();

        // Query for the current view state
        ApplicationViewState currentState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value;

        if (currentState != ApplicationViewState.Snapped)
        {
            App.DataMode = Mode.Featured;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(RestaurantSearchDetails));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Snapped is typically a view state and not a navigation.  When you snap you don't bring up a new page, you modify the presentation that's there, perhaps hiding everything and showing just a logo (in worst case). If you look at the default templates, you'll see they have a GridView and ListView, one shows in full mode, one in snapped, and simply the Visibility property changes - via ViewStateManager.GoToState(). The current page never changes.

Comment: I have the snapped SDK from Win8. How do I show a big image, based on the snap mode, and hide the rest of the screen? Can I do anything in App.xaml? I have about 4 or 5 screens and I would prefer not to repeat the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Reading and writing data sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Reading-and-writing-data-75ea10a3) shows how you can navigate between two different screens and change the layout for each screen depending on the view state, snapped vs. filled.